# How to get a fixed header to center taking scrollbar into account?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a calendar and the header contains in it the names of the days of the week (su, mo...). The calendar itself scrolls while I want the header to stay fixed. This part has been simple enough using position fixed or making the calendar div contain the scroll bar.

The big issue I have is that I centered both the dates and the days of the week and the scrollbar is making the center different on the header and the content. The only workaround I found to this was to remove the scrollbar entirely, but I want the scrollbar to be visible. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    .header-wrapper {
      padding-left: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
  }
  .content {
    padding-left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

Here is a watered down example of my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/3hpj0s8L/

Comment: Please give more details and code you implemented so far.

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: We can't fix code that we can't see

Comment: Ya sorry, working on it. There is a lot of code let me try to condense.

Comment: I added a watered down jsfiddle so you can see what my issue is

Comment: the jsfiddle cannot be all of the code needed to represent a calendar - and if that is all that you have as of now, you have much bigger problems

Comment: I only added the code necessary to illustrate my issue

Comment: Do you want the header text to be horizontally centered?

Comment: Yes, but I should add that there's a flex box in there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3hpj0s8L/5/

Comment: remove ".header-wrapper" class and on ".header" class add "left:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);" it will make the header centered. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave the `.wrapper` a `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to center all the child elements.

This makes the positioning of each child element with `padding`/`margin` and `transform: translate`, and even the `width` of the fixed element, obsolete.

Here is the updated **[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/3hpj0s8L/2/)**.

Comment: I thought of doing something like this the only issue is that it assumes the scrollbar is 8px. This will not always be the case, especially since this will be heavily, if not exclusively, used on mobile.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps I was too quick with my answer. I updated my answer with something better.

Comment: When I tidied the code in the JSFiddle it added extra space in the HTML code that removed the fixed text 1px away from the center. Just a heads up.

Comment: Huzzah it worked thanks, I've been sitting on this for a bit. Any chance you can fill me in as to why?

Comment: If you look [**here**](https://i.imgur.com/oyMCvq3.png) you will see that if you tidy the HTML in the JSFiddle, there is an extra space added somewhere, and if you remove all the extra space there is, it's gone again. Don't worry about it too much, I just wanted to point it out just in case you run into this problem, now you know it's the HTML and not the CSS. Good luck with the rest :)